# magento 1.7.0.2 - move shop from public_html/magento to public_html/

Tags: magento

I moved my shop to public_html directory. Before move I changed these things:

- System->configuration->web:

  - Base URL: http://www.domain.com/
  - Base Link URL:{{unsecure_base_url}}
  - Base Skin URL: {{unsecure_base_url}}skin/
  - Base Media URL: {{unsecure_base_url}}media/
  - Base JavaScript URL: {{unsecure_base_url}}js/
  - Base URL: https://www.domain.com/
  - Base Link URL: {{secure_base_url}}
  - Base Skin URL: {{secure_base_url}}skin/
  - Base Media URL: {{secure_base_url}}media/
  - Base JavaScript URL: {{secure_base_url}}js/
- in index.php delete all "magento/"
- in .htaccess i change "#RewriteBase magento/" to "#RewriteBase"

Then I checked and everything works fine: shop, category, product, sing up, selling.

But only one thing has a bad point. When I go to Magento Connect Manager and try install any module (never mind which one) I wait a very long time and eventually receive this error message:

```
community/Optimiseweb_CookieNotice: No releases for
'Optimiseweb_CookieNotice', skipping

community/Cubix_CookieLaw: No releases for 'Cubix_CookieLaw', skipping
```

Always this error:

> community/.... : No releases for `...`, skipping

Does anyone know what I must do to repair this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to check path in cookie in system-> general ->web -> session cookie management. If you have provided old path then change it with new.
If you dont get solved this error then you need to update this extension Cubix_CookieLaw.